# Generate Navbar In WordPress

Tags: menus

I am currently developing a custom theme.

I need to generate menu with submenu.

By default wordpress provides me result like below:

```
<ul id="side-menu" role="navigation" class="main-menu nav">

    <li class="selected" id="menu-item-485">
        <p> <a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/">Home</a> </p>
    </li>

    <li class="parent menu-item" id="menu-item-486">
        <p> <a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/">About Us</a> </p>

        <div>
            <ul id="side-menu" class="sub-menu-new">
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-488">
                    <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/values/">Values</a></p>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-489">
                    <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/vision-mission/">Vision & Mission</a></p>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-487">
                    <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/quality/">Quality</a></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I want the sub menu to come out from main ul.

I need to exact result as below:

```
<ul id="side-menu" role="navigation" class="main-menu nav">
    <li class="selected" id="menu-item-485">
        <p> <a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/">Home</a> </p>
    </li>

    <li class="parent menu-item" id="menu-item-486" data-submenuid="about">
        <p> <a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/">About Us</a> </p>
    </li>
 </ul>

<ul data-submenuid="about" id="side-menu" class="sub-menu-new">
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-488">
        <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/values/">Values</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-489">
        <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/vision-mission/">Vision & Mission</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-487">
        <p><a href="http://10.0.1.46/iir/sites/icegen/wordpress/IIR_icegen/about-us/quality/">Quality</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I tried using the below php class in wordpress but the result is failure

```
class menu_default_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth){
        $output .= '<div><ul class="sub-menu-new" id="side-menu">';
    }

    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output){
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        global $rb_submenus;

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $new_output = '';
        $open_class = '';
        $depth_class = ($args->has_children ? 'parent ' : '');

        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $current_indicators = array('current-menu-item','current-menu-parent','current_page_item','current_page_parent');

        $newClasses = array();
        foreach($classes as $el)
            if(in_array($el,$current_indicators))
            array_push($newClasses,$el);

        $class_names = join(' ',apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class',array_filter($newClasses),$item));

        if(strpos($class_names, 'current-menu-parent') > 0 || strpos($class_names, 'current_page_parent') > 0) {
            $class_names = ' class="' . $depth_class . $open_class . 'opened"';
        } else if($class_names != '') {
            $class_names = ' class="' . $depth_class . $open_class . 'selected"';
        } else if($class_names == '') {
            $class_names = ' class="' . $depth_class . $open_class . 'menu-item"';
        }

        if ( !get_post_meta( $item->object_id , '_members_only' , true ) || is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $class_names . '>';
        }

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        if($item->object != 'portfolio_category' && $item->object != 'gallery_category')
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        else
            $attributes .= ' href="#"';

        $portfolio_count;
        $gallery_count;

        if($item->object == 'portfolio_category'){
            $terms = get_terms('portfolio_category', array('include' => $item->object_id));
            $portfolio_count = $terms[0]->count;
            $attributes .= ' data-category="true" data-filter="' . $terms[0]->slug .'"';
        }

        if($item->object == 'gallery_category'){
            $terms = get_terms('gallery_category', array('include' => $item->object_id));
            $gallery_count = $terms[0]->count;
            $attributes .= ' data-category="true" data-filter="' . $terms[0]->slug .'"';
        }

        if($item->attr_title == 'allportfolio' || $item->attr_title == 'allgallery'){
            $attributes .= ' data-all="true" data-filter="*"';
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<p><a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ($item->object == 'category' ? ' ('. get_category($item->object_id)->count . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= ($item->object == 'portfolio_category' ? ' ('. $portfolio_count . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= ($item->object == 'gallery_category' ? ' ('. $gallery_count . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= ($item->attr_title == 'allblog' ? ' ('. wp_count_posts()->publish . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= ($item->attr_title == 'allportfolio' ? ' ('. wp_count_posts('portfolio')->publish . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= ($item->attr_title == 'allgallery' ? ' ('. wp_count_posts('gallery')->publish . ')' : '');
        $item_output .= '</a></p>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        if ( !get_post_meta( $item->object_id, '_members_only' , true ) || is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        $output .= $new_output;

    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
        if ( !get_post_meta( $item->object_id, '_members_only' , true ) || is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {

        $output .= "</ul></div>\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like overkill for something a few lines of CSS could fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript to move the Submenu items where ever you please.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        (function ($) { 
            $('.sub-menu-new').after( $('.main-menu') );        

        })(jQuery);
    });

</script>
```

OR...

You could take a look at the `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter hook

It could allow you to do a check against every menu item and maybe store the submenu items somewhere else to be displayed elsewhere

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'your_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
function your_wp_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary'):
        foreach($items as $item):
            //only display items you want; and store the other items for later output
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

BUT I WOULD NOT WASTE TIME DOING THAT.  Why don't you just make more than one menu and output them where you please?